# Huggingface datasets.DatasetDict gives only labels to transform preprocessing method

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to use Huggingface's datasets and transformers libraries to train a model on the CIFAR10 dataset. For the specific model I'm using however, there needs to be preprocessing on the images, which I do using the `.with_transform()` method. When picking individual datapoints for visualizing or testing, everything works. However when I use the `Trainer` class and its `.train()` method, something breaks.

If I include a print statement in my preprocessing function, I get that the input to the function is:

```py
{'label': [8, 1, 8, 9, 0, 5, 5, 5]}
```

Whereas if I pick a single datapoint I would get:

```py
>>> print(data['train'][0])
{'img': <PIL image object>, 'label': 0}
```

This results in a KeyError when I try to access `'img'` from the dictionary. I can't figure out why it passes only the labels to the preprocessing function. I get that there are multiple labels because it's processing in batches, but why are the images removed? I've also tried renaming the `'img'` key in the datapoints to `'image'` but this did not help.

Here is my code:

```py
from torchvision.models import mobilenet_v3_small, MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
import evaluate
from datasets import load_dataset

weights = MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1
preprocess = weights.transforms()

raw_data = load_dataset("cifar10")


def transform(x):
    print("x")
    print(x)
    return dict(x, img=[preprocess(img) for img in x["img"]])


data = raw_data.with_transform(transform)

print("data['train'][0]\n", data["train"][0])  # works

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch"
)
accuracy = evaluate.load("accuracy")


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return accuracy.compute(
        predictions=predictions,
        references=labels,
    )


model = mobilenet_v3_small(
    weights=weights,
)
model.train()

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=data["train"].select(range(5000)),
    eval_dataset=data["test"].select(range(1000)),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()  # keyError
```

Comment: hello, you would go a step forward by adding "remove_unused_columns=False" in "training_args". Then you would need to make your model trainable. 
So far, your funtion model.forward() is only made to output a prediction, it does not allow for a "label" parameter that would be usefull for training.